# Executing methods from the same class in parallel with minimal overhead

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have a class Algorithm which has 2 complicated, time consuming methods, say method1 and method2. I have to create multiple instances of this class, and query resp. method1 and method 2 for each of these instances in parallel. The following code pretty much achieves this:

```
private final List<Algorithm> algorithms;

private final ExecutorService executor;
private final List<Future<Void>> futures;

public AlgorithmManager(List<Algorithm> algorithms){
    this.algorithms=algorithms;

    //Define workers
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Constants.MAXTHREADS); //Creates a threat pool consisting of MAXTHREADS threats
    futures=new ArrayList<Future<Void>>(algorithms.size());
}

/**
 * Procedure to solve method1 for each algorithm in parallel
 */
public double[] solveMethod1(){
    double[] results=new double[algorithms.size()];
    List<FutureTask<Double>> taskList=new ArrayList<FutureTask<Double>>();

    //submit all the relevant tasks to solve method1
    for(Algorithm pp : algorithms){
        FutureTask<Double> futureTask = new FutureTask<Double>(new Callable<Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double call() {
                return pp.solveMethod1();  //SolveMethod1
            }
        });

        taskList.add(futureTask);
        executor.submit(futureTask);
    }

    //Query the results of each task one by one
    for(int i=0; i<algorithms.size(); i++){
        results[i]=taskList.get(i).get();
    }

    return results;
}

/**
 * Procedure to solve method2 for each algorithm in parallel
 */
public int[] solveMethod2(){
    int[] results=new double[algorithms.size()];
    List<FutureTask<Integer>> taskList=new ArrayList<FutureTask<Integer>>();

    //submit all the relevant tasks to solve method1
    for(Algorithm pp : algorithms){
        FutureTask<Integer> futureTask = new FutureTask<Integer>(new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() {
                return pp.solveMethod2();  //SolveMethod2
            }
        });

        taskList.add(futureTask);
        executor.submit(futureTask);
    }

    //Query the results of each task one by one
    for(int i=0; i<algorithms.size(); i++){
        results[i]=taskList.get(i).get();
    }

    return results;
}
```

The thing that bothers me is the overhead induced by all the FutureTask objects being created, each time solveMethod1 or solveMethod2 is invoked (this happens very often!). The problem is that, according to the JavaDoc you cannot reuse a FutureTask object, i.e. I cant execute the same FutureTask multiple times, so I have to create a new instance of the object every time I want to execute any of the methods.
I have thought about making the class Algorithm callable, thereby adding a method:

```
@Override
public Double call() throws Exception {
    return this.method1();
}
```

This way I can simply submit the Algorithm instances to the executor, but I can only do this for 1 method?
Any suggestions on how to improve this implementation, in a clean and efficient manner? Unfortunately it is undesirable to put method1 and method2 into 2 different classes as they highly depend on each others data structures.

Btw, this is a simplified code-snippet. In my real code, method1 and method2 can also throw exceptions.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but your answer to "bothering about overhead" is the wrong approach. If you think you have a performance problem, then analyze the runtime behavior of your application to **really** understand what is going on. In other words: do you really think the overhead of creating a few objects will come into play when your actual computations are that complex? Don't start "optimizing" your code without understanding what your **real** problem is. See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Often, programming something sloppy, and programming something properly take about the same amount of effort. Since I often re-use my code, I rather learn how to implement this properly from the start. Hence my question. Besides that, I do agree that this certainly won't be the bottleneck of my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overhead is  probably minimal but your code is unnecessarily complicated with the FutureTasks. So I suggest that you simplify and clean up your code a bit by using Callables & Futures instead. In short you can use the following methods and insert them where relevant in your code.

```
Callable<Double> c = new Callable<Double> () { ... };
Future<Double> f = executor.submit(c);
Double result = f.get();
```

Comment: Great, that's indeed cleaner, and no need to reallocate new objects. Thanks!